# What mode for a 16 bit unsigned raw binary image file?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, binary-data, grayscale

Using the Python Imaging Library to make a conversion to an image I get an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\workspace\colorCorrect\src\editGrayscale.py", line 24, in <module>
    changed.save(saveFile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1423, in save
    raise KeyError(ext) # unknown extension
KeyError: '.bin'
```

My code:

```
import Image
#file to save:  C:\Users\name\imagedata\visiblespec.bin

fileName = raw_input("Enter a file name: ")
saveFile = raw_input("Enter a new save file name: ")

with open(fileName, 'rb') as f:
im = Image.fromstring('L', (3032, 2016), f.read()) # also try 'L;16B', 'I;16', and 'I;16B'
changed = im.point(lambda i: i/2)
changed.save(saveFile)
```

Image is a grayscale 16 bit unsigned integer 11 MB binary file.

Comment: What happened? I thought the answer I gave you yesterday worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10902279/5987

Comment: @MarkRansom I was switching things around and your code worked great when I just wanted to display it but when I try to save it I cannot do it in the same file format that I wanted to originally.

Comment: @clifgray Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the valid modes for PIL are listed in the source file [`unpack.c`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/libImaging/Unpack.c#L1510), near the bottom of the file. I'd start with the ones containing `16`.

Given your edits there are other problems. First is that PIL.Image needs to determine an encoder for writing out the file, and it does this using the filename extension. Your `.bin` file extension is non-standard so there's no way to know which format to use. Try something like `.png`.

Second problem is that not every file type supports every image format. You may need to convert the image before you save it.

```
changed.convert('L').save(saveFile)
```

Given your last comment you just want to write the values back out to a raw format file. You can try the `'raw'` format or just use `tostring` to write to a file yourself.

```
changed.save(saveFile, 'raw')
```